# Loop through Ansible playbook nested array

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am having issue looping through my json file, but it's looping through all the `topicPermissions` instead of just the topic for each individual user.

Ideally it would loop through and create something like this

```
user: Larry
  - topic: TopicX
  - Permission: read, describe

  - topic: TopicY
  - Permission: write, describe
```

and then move on to

user: Tommy..... and so on

This is my code:

```yaml
- name: Create ACL for each user
  vars:
    my_json_data: "{{ lookup('file', 'test.json') }}"
  shell: "rpk acl create --allow-principal {{ item.0.id }} --operation {{ item.1.permissions }} --topic {{ item.1.topic }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ my_json_data.user }}"
    - "{{ my_json_data.user | json_query('[].topicPermissions[].{permissions: permissions, topic: topic}') }}"
  when: item.1.permissions is defined and item.1.topic is defined
```

Here is my Json file:

```json
{
    "admin":[
       {
          "roleId": "placeholder",
          "secretPath": "placeholder",
          "vaultAddr": "placeholder",
          "brokers": "placeholder",
          "containerName": "placeholder"
       }
    ],
    "topicsToCreate":[
       "TopicX", "TopicY", "TopicZ"
    ],
    "user":[
       {
       "id":"Larry",
       "userpassword":"placeholder",
       "consumerGroupPermissions":[
          {
             "groupId":"Apple",
             "groupPermissions":"read,describe"
          }
       ],
       "topicPermissions":[
          {
             "topic":"TopicX",
             "permissions":"read,describe"
          },
          {
             "topic":"TopicY",
             "permissions":"write,describe"
          }
       ]
       },
       {
          "id":"Tommy",
          "userpassword":"placeholder",
          "consumerGroupPermissions":[
             {
                "groupId":"Apple",
                "groupPermissions":"read,write,describe"
             }
          ],
          "topicPermissions":[
             {
                "topic":"TopicZ",
                "permissions":"read,write,describe"
             },
             {
                "topic":"TopicY",
                "permissions":"write,describe"
             },
             {
                "topic":"TopicX",
                "permissions":"read,describe"
             }
          ]
      }
    ]
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the list of users

```yaml
my_json_data:
  user:
    - consumerGroupPermissions:
      - {groupId: Apple, groupPermissions: 'read,describe'}
      id: Larry
      topicPermissions:
      - {permissions: 'read,describe', topic: TopicX}
      - {permissions: 'write,describe', topic: TopicY}
      userpassword: placeholder
    - consumerGroupPermissions:
      - {groupId: Apple, groupPermissions: 'read,write,describe'}
      id: Tommy
      topicPermissions:
      - {permissions: 'read,write,describe', topic: TopicZ}
      - {permissions: 'write,describe', topic: TopicY}
      - {permissions: 'read,describe', topic: TopicX}
      userpassword: placeholder
```

---

A: Loop the list with [*subelements*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html)

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.id }} {{ item.1.topic }} {{ item.1.permissions }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ my_json_data.user }}"
        - topicPermissions
```

gives (abridged) what you want

```yaml
  msg: Larry TopicX read,describe
  msg: Larry TopicY write,describe
  msg: Tommy TopicZ read,write,describe
  msg: Tommy TopicY write,describe
  msg: Tommy TopicX read,describe
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: test.json
        name: my_json_data
    - debug:
        var: my_json_data

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.id }} {{ item.1.topic }} {{ item.1.permissions }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ my_json_data.user }}"
        - topicPermissions
```

---

The best practice is to keep users in a dictionary. Simplify the structure. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat users.yaml 
users:
  Larry:
    groups:
    - {id: Apple, permissions: 'read,describe'}
    passwd: placeholder
    topics:
    - {permissions: 'read,describe', topic: TopicX}
    - {permissions: 'write,describe', topic: TopicY}
  Tommy:
    groups:
    - {id: Apple, permissions: 'read,write,describe'}
    passwd: placeholder
    topics:
    - {permissions: 'read,write,describe', topic: TopicZ}
    - {permissions: 'write,describe', topic: TopicY}
    - {permissions: 'read,describe', topic: TopicX}
```

Then, the playbook below gives the same results

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - include_vars: users.yaml
    - debug:
        var: users

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1.topic }} {{ item.1.permissions }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ users|dict2items }}"
        - value.topics
```

Comment: tyvm! This works for me